# How to fetch monthly attendance report for a student from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to show monthly attendance report for a particular student from mysql table. I need result like below,

I have attendance table in my database which is:

```
class_id ses_id sec_id student_id att_date   remarks taken
      11      1     17         13 2016-03-28       1 2016-03-28 19:22:23
      11      1     17         14 2016-03-28       1 2016-03-28 19:22:23
      11      1     17         15 2016-03-28       1 2016-03-28 19:22:23
      11      1     17         19 2016-03-28       1 2016-03-28 19:22:23
      11      1     17         20 2016-03-28       1 2016-03-28 19:22:23
      11      1     17         13 2016-03-29       1 2016-03-29 14:25:46
      11      1     17         14 2016-03-29       1 2016-03-29 14:25:46
      11      1     17         15 2016-03-29       1 2016-03-29 14:25:46
      11      1     17         19 2016-03-29       1 2016-03-29 14:25:46
      11      1     17         20 2016-04-05       0 2016-03-31 20:07:23
      10      1     36         17 2016-04-01       0 2016-04-01 08:32:21
      10      1     37         16 2016-04-01       1 2016-04-01 08:32:41
      11      1     17         17 2017-01-01       1 2016-04-01 08:52:39
```

I want to fetch data from my attendance table where **remarks '1' means present** like below:
I need mysql query to fetch the data like below

**Please anyone help me to write query**

My query is

```
SELECT YEAR(att_date) AS y, MONTH(att_date) AS m, COUNT(DISTINCT att_date) FROM attendance WHERE class_id=11 AND student_id=15 GROUP BY y, m
```

But didn't got the expected result as below

For **student-ID- 15**

```
CLASS   STUDENT_ID  YEAR    MONTH   TOTAL_CLASSES   TOTAL_PRESENT

11      15      2016    April         21             20
11      15      2016    May           25             25
11      15      2016    June          30             29
11      15      2016    July          18             18
11      15      2017    January       28             28
```

Comment: Is this data in that format in table?

Comment: What result you expect?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: wheres the code that shows what you have tried?

Comment: And where is the sample data? How do we know what your tables look like? Only magic can write a query without that

Comment: post your database tables and php code you tried

Comment: Please read my question now I have updated my question.

Comment: I cannot understand how you derive that result set from that data set. Incidentally, remarks should probably be an integer, not a string

Answer (score 0):

Write code like below

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE STUDENT_ID  ='1234'"; //condition
$result   = mysql_query($query) or  die(mysql_error()); //query result
$count    = mysql_num_rows($result); //rows it return
if($count > 0) 
{
   //all fetching
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
              $CLASS   =$row['CLASS'];
               $YEAR    =$row['YEAR'];
               $MONTH   =$row['MONTH'];
               $TOTAL_CLASSES=$row['TOTAL_CLASSES'];
               $TOTAL_PRESENT=$row['TOTAL_PRESENT'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I just don't think we should be promoting a deprecated and insecure API

Comment: @Strawberry what do you wanna say i am not understanding anything

Answer (score -1):

```
 $getquery = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE STUDENT_ID  ='15'";
            $result   = mysql_query($getquery) or
                    die( mysql_error());

            $count    = mysql_numrows($result);
             if( $count>0){
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                       $CLASS   =$row['class_id'];
                       $YEAR    =date("Y",strtotime($row['att_date']));
                       $MONTH   =date("m",strtotime($row['att_date']));
                         $section=$row['sec_id'];



                        }
    }
    then use the these datas in your display table..
```